# Getting Spring to work with 3-tier web system with Tomcat

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am working on adding new features to an existing Java EE project which involves three tiers: Data, Business and Presentation. Spring 2.5 and JDK 1.4.2 has been used.

The business tier (Domain object project) uses Spring to manage jdbc transactions and inject DAOs and services as normal. It has "Spring-config.xml" to configure Spring. It works well.

The presentation tier is going to use Spring 2.5 , plain JSP and Tomcat 5.0. However, I am stuck at setting up web.xml to load Spring when the project starts up.

The web.xml is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>TestSpring25Web</display-name>
<listener>
    <description>
  loads the spring application context on startup
</description>
    <display-name>spring application context loader listener</display-name>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:web-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:Spring-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>businessBeanFactory</param-value>
</context-param>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<!-- DWR -->
<servlet>
    <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The error stack trace of Tomcat 5 is like:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group     definition. Group resource name [classpath:Spring-config.xml], factory key     [businessBeanFactory]; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML     document from class path resource [Spring-config.xml]; nested exception is     java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:336)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:186)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
```

It obviously complains the "Spring-config.xml" is not found; but the domain project has been set as dependency of the web project.

I am new to Spring, but could anyone help give me some tips? THANKS

Any best practice regarding configuring a 3-tier Spring project like this?

Comment: Why are you using such outdated versions of Java, Spring and Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Spring-config-xml must be on the root classpath. You don't explain where this file is located and how you deploy your application in Tomcat.